# Can shrinking temporary TEMP tablespace in Oracle cause any harm?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, tablespaces

I have a massive TEMP tablespace that is 1TB large. It consists of 30datafiles, each one is like 31GB in size.

Entire TEMP tablespace has a size of 1TB, while used size is only ~600MB.

I want to shrink tablespace and I am dilema whether to use option

**a)** to shrink each datafile individually:

```
    ALTER TABLESPACE temp SHRINK TEMPFILE '/u02/oracle/data/lmtemp01.dbf' KEEP 10MB
    ALTER TABLESPACE temp SHRINK TEMPFILE '/u02/oracle/data/lmtemp02.dbf' KEEP 10MB
    ALTER TABLESPACE temp SHRINK TEMPFILE '/u02/oracle/data/lmtemp03.dbf' KEEP 10MB
```

...

or

**b)** to shrink entire tablespace:

```
    ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP SHRINK SPACE KEEP 300MB;
```

**c)** shrink without KEEP (so it gets shrunk to minimum)

```
   ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP SHRINK SPACE;
```

I am on Oracle Enterprise 12.2.

I am wondering:

1. Which option is the 'best' ?
2. Why wouldn't one just always use option C ?
3. Why would one want to KEEP anything in TEMP temporary tablespace at
   all at shrinking (except that bare system required minimum)?
4. Can any harm be done with shrinking TEMP tablespace? I will run it
       on Productional database (out of working hours tho when noone is connected to the DB) and I have to be sure.

I am running on Oracle Enterprise 12.2.

Comment: Temp spaces expand when the system needs space for interim work.  Why do you think that the normal work load will not cause the temporary space to expand after shrinking again?

Comment: Because there is a possibility that the next work load will not cause as large tablespace expansion as it's current size. Also, my customer uses Jenkins automation tool for their work load - I was thinking about adding script for shrinking TEMP tablespace after their each last work load job.  My customer has 20 databases and by shrinking TEMP tablespace at least for temporary (after each work load) I will save some storage, in theory of course : )

Comment: Storage is (relatively) cheap compared to downtime. Until you know what work load is causing the growth and the likelihood of it's reoccurence you are taking on risk for no proven gain.  Try  dba_extents where tablespace_name = 'TEMP' to gather more information about the growth of the temp space

Comment: May I ask you  what risk would I be taking by shrinking TEMP ?  Isn't shrinking TEMP harmless if it's done out of the working hours (with no active sessions) ?Well If had ASH - active session history, It would be easy to find out what's filling TEMP, but I don't have ASH unfortunately.

Comment: My comment is based on working with production systems on an enterprise level.  If the database is for development or not used for anything important then it might not apply.  For any change to a production database, particularly one which could terminate an in process transaction, the first question is "Why?". The idea that shrinking the temp space will not have any side effects depends on a number of assumptions:  assumes no work will be done while you are shrinking the temp files, assumes that downtime has no cost, assumes that the script will always run correctly.

Comment: Well if your exadata storage is completely full (all the racks) then buying additional disks is out of the question unfortunately :/  I just monitored TEMP during the work load and it didn't grow larger than 20GB. So I am not sure how it got 1TB in size at the first place.      I now tried to shrink datafiles that are 32GB in size,  while used size is only like 20MB. I can't shrink it coz it says that minimum shrinking size can be 32GB.  So I guess I will have to create new TEMP2 tablespace, make it as default temporary tablespace,drop original TEMP and then recreate TEMP and drop TEMP2

Comment: As Philip Schlump perfectly described in his answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824572/how-to-shrink-temp-tablespace-in-oracle

Answer (score 1):

all the three options would work, but would prefer to use first or the second one in production environment to avoid queries failing post activity due to not enough temp tablespace. Would recommend identifying the usage history pattern using queries similar to the one defined in this blog and then use that for your keep size.
https://zukus.blogspot.com/2016/06/temp-tablespace-usage-history.html